# Extend many line of a given distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, extend

I have a feature with hundreds of lines and I need to extend all the lines of a given distance (for example all of 100 meter).

Is there a function in [ArcGIS](https://www.arcgis.com) to do it automatically?

Comment: Extend in what direction? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: In the same direction aof the original line. In now they are straight line and i at the and i still want straight lines with the same direction but longer as in original. I need it to make profile of a river, but now the lines dont cover the whole river

Comment: Try [Extend Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/extend-line.htm). I have not tried it but it seems you need to have a "stop" feature in the same feature class as the input. For example try buffering the river, convert to polyline and append this to the input. Then run the tool

Comment: That could work for most cases but I will have problems where the lines will intersecate itself before   reaching the stop feature

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the ArcMap application of the ArcGIS Desktop product.  You have tagged the latter, but then you have supplied a link to ArcGIS Online within your question body.

To do this I think you should test the [Extend Line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/extend-line.htm) tool which:

> extends line segments to the first intersecting feature within a
> specified distance. If no intersecting feature is within the specified
> distance, the line segment will not be extended.

If this does not meet all of your line extending requirements then you may want to include a picture and description of one requirement that it does not meet within your question.